# Fedora Workstation 23 doesn't recognise 128GB USB

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, fedora-23

I'm trying to install Fedora 23 onto a 128GB USB 3 stick, which will be the basis for my NAS solution.

I've used Fedora Image Writer to put Fedora 23 onto the drive, and I can successfully boot to the installation screen, however when I get to this point [image: Installation Destination]the USB doesn't show up under Local Standard Devices.

I've tried putting the image onto an 8GB USB, getting to this point and selecting the 128 that way, but it still doesn't show up. However the 8GB does show up. The 128 *does* show up in the BIOS, so it is being seen, just not by Fedora.

Is it not possible to install fedora onto a very large USB? Could it be a hardware problem of some kind?

Comment: Use Fedora 24, 25 or 26. Fedora 23 is [EOL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life)

Comment: @Jakuje Unfortunately the NAS solution I'm using hasn't been released for 25 yet (Amahi, https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Amahi_10). The most up-to-date version is Amahi 9 on 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that despite the standard file system for Linux is Ext4, I needed to format the USB as NTFS.